# How to disable the "paylater" funding on the PayPal JavaScript SDK Button

Tags: paypal

I'm using the latest PayPal JavaScript SDK and I'm trying to disable the "pay later" funding. The documentation is simple and clear: https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/configuration/#link-disablefunding

Steps to reproduce:

1. Visit https://www.paypal.com/buttons/smart and click "Copy Code" without modifying any setting
2. Replace both `USD` with `EUR`
3. Add `&disable-funding=paylater` to the list of query parameters
4. Click the button and log in with your sandbox account

The "pay later" option is still there.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To disable the Pay Later button from being rendered as one of the PayPal buttons on your site (next the yellow PayPal one or black Debit or Credit Card one, generally), use `&disable-funding=paylater`. You only control what happens on your own page.
- Once a payer clicks to go over to the PayPal page, and especially once they sign in, which funding sources will be available are between that payer and PayPal. You do not control this, and indeed you will not be informed which funding source is selected. Billing and funding source information in their account is kept private by design; all you know and really need to be concerned about is receiving a successful PayPal payment.

Comment: I still got this paylater show when click to checkout butotn

Comment: On the PayPal checkout page? Yes, you do not control that -- and it will be different for payers in different countries (most don't have Pay Later and may see some other local funding method). Read the above, you only control which buttons appear on your site.